# how to test equality of data class with OffsetDateTime attribute?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-mvc, mockk

I have an attribute in a DTO and Entity defined like this:

```
val startDate: OffsetDateTime,
```

The dto has a `toEntity` method:

```
data class SomeDTO(
  val id: Long? = null,
  val startDate: OffsetDateTime,
  ) {

    fun toEntity(): SomeEntity {
      return SomeEntity(
        id = id,
        startDate = startDate,
      )
    }
}
```

And a controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/some/api")
class SomeController(
  private val someService: SomeService,
) {
  @PostMapping("/new")
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
  suspend fun create(@RequestBody dto: SomeDTO): SomeEntity {
    return someService.save(dto.toEntity())
  }
}
```

And I have a failing test:

```
  @Test
  fun `create Ok`() {
    val expectedId = 123L

    val zoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")
    val dto = SomeDTO(
      id = null,
      startDate = LocalDate.of(2021, 4, 23)
        .atStartOfDay(zoneId).toOffsetDateTime(),
    )
    val expectedToStore = dto.toEntity()
    val stored = expectedToStore.copy(id = expectedId)

    coEvery { someService.save(any()) } returns stored

    client
      .post()
      .uri("/some/api/new")
      .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      .bodyValue(dto)
      .exchange()
      .expectStatus().isCreated
      .expectBody()
      .jsonPath("$.id").isEqualTo(expectedId)

    coVerify {
      someService.save(expectedToStore)
    }
  }
```

The test fails for the `coVerify` because the `startDate` does not match:

```
Verification failed: ...
... arguments are not matching:
[0]: argument: SomeEntity(id=null, startDate=2021-04-22T22:00Z),
matcher: eq(SomeEntity(id=null, startDate=2021-04-23T00:00+02:00)),
result: -
```

Semantically, the `startDate`s match, but the timezone is different. I wonder how I can enforce `coVerify` to either use a proper semantic comparison for type `OffsetDateTime` or how I can enforce the internal format of `OffsetDateTime`=? Or what other approach should we use to verify the `expectedToStore` value is passed to `someService.save(...)` ?

I could use `withArgs` but it is cumbersome:

```
coVerify {
  someService.save(withArg {   
    assertThat(it.startDate).isEqualTo(expectedToStore.startDate)
    // other manual asserts
 })
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code that you are trying to test? Thanks!

Comment: @JoãoDias I added the (trivial) controller code that is under test and also added the `withArgs` workaround which is still too cumbersome

Comment: @Stuck I tried to get a minimal reproduction running, but something in your code does not align up. Your `toEntity` function expected a non-nullable `Long` and has no default value, but in both your implementation and test, you do not pass any value as parameter. Also, the function does not make use of the parameter `userId` at all. Would you be so kind and align the code to be runnable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Add this to your `application.properties`:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.adjust-dates-to-context-time-zone=false
```

This way, the offset will be deserialized as retrieved and not altered.

---

I created a (slightly modified) reproduction repository [on GitHub](https://github.com/EndzeitBegins/spring-equality-offsetdatetime). Inside the Controller the value of `dto.startDate` is already `2021-04-22T22:00Z`, thus at UTC.

By default, the serialization library used "Jackson" aligns all offsets during deserialization to the same configured offset.
The default offset used is `+00:00` or `Z`, which resembles UTC.

You can enable / disable this behaviour over the property `spring.jackson.deserialization.adjust-dates-to-context-time-zone={true false}` and set the timezone with `spring.jackson.time-zone=<timezone>`

Alternatively, you can force to align the offset with an other timezone during deserialization:

```
spring.jackson.time-zone=Europe/Berlin
```

This way, the offset will be the aligned with the timezone `Europe/Berlin`.